System has no available disk capacity or no available BE nodes
When I tried to create a table in Apache Doris 2.0.3 in mac OS 13.3.1 like this:
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dolphin.example_tbl
    -> (
    ->     `user_id` LARGEINT NOT NULL COMMENT "user id",
    ->     `date` DATE NOT NULL COMMENT "import date"
    -> )
    -> AGGREGATE KEY(`user_id`, `date`)
    -> DISTRIBUTED BY HASH(`user_id`) BUCKETS 1
    -> PROPERTIES (
    ->     "replication_allocation" = "tag.location.default: 1"
    -> );
ERROR 1105 (HY000): errCode = 2, detailMessage = System has no available disk capacity or no available BE nodes

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? BTW, the database create success.
